# In .net store the data in textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 8 values in array and i want to show these values into 5 different text box.But when i show that values it is in following format:

```
TextBox1 :- Values 1 ,Values2
TextBox2 :- Values 3 ,Values4
TextBox3 :- Values 5 ,Values6
TextBox4 :- Values 7
TextBox5 :- Values 8
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: yes..i want to show data in above format

Comment: you should not store values in the gui...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than storing data in an `asp:TextBox`, you should consider some other methods of storing values.
For example, you can use the `HttpApplicationState` class in `System.Web` to store a variety of different data types. If you wanted to store a `DataTable` using this method, you could do so by doing something like this in C#:
`Application["data"] = x;`

(x being a `DataTable`)

```
DataTable y = (DataTable)Application["data"];
```

Another way of storing data can be using `HttpSession` variables which can be done in the same way using C#:

```
Session["name"] = "TestUserName";
String x = Session["name"].ToString();
```

More information about:
[HttpApplicationState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate(v=vs.110).aspx)
[HttpSessionState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

ASP:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt2"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt3"></asp:TextBox>
```

C#:

```
ArrayList x = new ArrayList();
x.Add("One");
x.Add("Two");
x.Add("Three");

txt1.Text = x[0].ToString(); // "One"
txt2.Text = x[1].ToString(); // "Two"
txt3.Text = x[2].ToString(); // "Three"
```

The above shows how you can input data into an `asp:TextBox`, but it's bad practice to store data in them for using elsewhere. This is only for inputting values into them as shown in this example.
Remember, when dealing with arrays, the first value isn't `[1]`, it's actually `[0]`, so keep this in mind when you're using this method to write array values into textboxes.